# Scope of global variable in function called by admin_post_{action}

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom register form, that utilize the admin_post_{action} hook to call a function which does all the processing for the form. The functions.php file contains a function like this one.

```
<?php

    $example = 'test';

    function create_client_account(){
       //check username isn't a duplicate
       //check email isn't a duplicate
       //scrub all data
       //create an array of errors

      if($errors){
         global $example

         echo $example //outputs 'test'

         $example = new WP_Error();
         $example->add('test',$errors);

         var_dump($example) //outputs WP_Error object
      }

    }

   add_action( 'admin_post_create_account', 'create_client_account' );
   add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_create_account', 'create_client_account' );
?>
```

then I have a template file page-register.php where I try to access the global variable, but it does not work. All the processing is correct and if I do a `var_dump($example)` in the function all output is there. But if I do it in the template file the output is NULL.

```
<?php 
  global $example;
  var_dump($example); //outputs 'test'
?>
```

I have pinpointed the issue down to a scope issue where that global is no longer available after execution of the function, I believe this is due to the action hook but I am unsure.

My question is how do I then make this work? How do I make that global available outside of the function.

Comment: I could suggest you to initialize the global variable outside the function like this: <?php $example = 0; function create_client...

Comment: @user3647971 if I set the variable outside the function it becomes available in the template. But for some reason the function does not modify the value of the variable.

Comment: It's because variable $errors is not set or does not have any value that evaluates as "true"

Comment: if the $errors is an array you can try: if(!empty($errors)) or if(count($errors) > 0)

Comment: @user3647971 hey the errors are generated and outputted correctly. The logic is right. It's the scope of the variable this is messing things up. see updated code

Comment: The code seems to be correct. See another suggestion in my answer.

Comment: There's also the possibility that your code is called asynchronously or that the hooking only registers the functions and they are used asynchronously and thus the global never exists in the scope

Comment: @user3647971 how could i check into that? that is what I believe is happening, I implemented your code sample and got the same results.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how wordpress works, but I doubt it's supposed to be used this way. PHP variables are available only for that one run at a time, they won't be remembered when another action is taken on website. Unless you use $_SESSION or databases or cookies

Comment: so then the question becomes to I save my errors object to a cookie or the session instead? or follow the other ways I have seen where they just redirect with get parameters with error messages.

Comment: If you need the errors for later use why not. But sure redirect is always a good option.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define the variable outside function scope:

```
<?php 
$example = 0;

function create_client_account(){
       //check username isn't a duplicate
       //check email isn't a duplicate
       //scrub all data
       //create an array of errors

      if($errors){//you should set and assign this $errors somewhere too
         $GLOBALS['example'] = new WP_Error();
         $GLOBALS['example']->add('test',$errors);
      }
}
```

Then try to access it like you did before

```
<?php 
  global $example;
  var_dump($example);
?>
```